# Is is possible to maintain chat messages in static props in .net mvc and c#?

Tags: c#, android, asp.net-mvc, chat

I am trying to create chat in my android app.
My server Technology is Asp.Net Mvc 5 .

I want to use static props as chat message store , I think that using one static property , will slow the pushing and pulling messages.

```
public static List<ChatMessage> messages;
private static readonly Object obj = new Object();

...
public void static AddToMessage(ChatMessage chatMessage){
lock (obj){
...
}
}
```

Comment: You will exhaust your memory very soon. There is so many cool new technologies for web applications, but you are using static property with lock object?

Comment: Also, do you mean to send a history of `ChatMessage` to your clients at start of their android app? Mobile user will not thank you for gigabytes of useless network traffic.

Comment: As for me, [ASP.Net SignalR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-signalr) (or better [ASP.Net Core SignalR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/introduction?view=aspnetcore-2.2)) are just perfect to write chat apps.

Comment: Yeah signalr for the win

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes, but for the love of all things good and wonderful in this world, please don't.  It's just terribly bad design and fraught with problems. Every time the apppool recycles or crashes you will lose everything.

Use a database for persistence instead.

Comment: I think you should switch the order of _"terribly bad design"_ and _"app pool recycles"_. This is what Steve McConnell means by **Coding Horror** :)